# Nginx rewrite rules

Tags: url-rewriting, query, nginx

I am having some problems with the Nginx rewrite algorithm for WordPress.

I am using this for the rewrite and it works good;

```
    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
    if ($host != 'domain.com') {
    rewrite ^/(.*)     http://domain.com/$1 permanent;
    }
```

it makes this url;

```
http://domain.com/?author=1
```

to this;

```
http://domain.com/author/username/
```

which is good but with an url like this;

```
http://domain.com/?author=1&type=like
```

it makes it;

```
http://domain.com/author/username/?type=like
```

and i am not getting any error but the query is not working.

What i am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The correct Nginx rewrite rules for WordPress are:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

This sends everything through index.php and keeps the appended query string intact.

If your running PHP-FPM you should also add this before your fastcgi_params as a security measure:

```
location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri =404;
        
      //  fastcgi_param ....
      //  fastcgi_param ....
      
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Comment: Chris thank you. Can you look at my whole code , is it looks correct right now? http://pastebin.com/DiMc6YtD ALSO where should i add the try files uri 404 in this? thanks.

Comment: no this is giving me duplicate cause i have already have location php. can you help chris?

Comment: okat i combined it like that and now everything works fine; http://pastebin.com/fuKwuCe1 but can you look at my whole code and tell me if i have any security issues? thanks

Comment: Change line 70 to `try_files $uri = 404;` See [Nginx 0 day exploit](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,88845,169967#msg-169967) for more info.

Comment: thank you very much chris! by the way the site you give is adding 403 not 404. what is the difference?

Comment: 403 is forbidden error and 404 is page not found.  Either one will work.

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that the **&** character between $uri **'&'** $args is very important, as it will partially work without it, but will fail in some cases.

**Correct:**

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

**Wrong:**

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$args;
}
```

The wrong method will manage to handle multiple args:

```
https://example.com?myvar=xxx&secvar=xxx // Will work
```

But fail if only one arg is passed:

```
https://example.com?myvar=xxx // Will NOT work
```

This made it really hard to find the typo for me, but at least I learned something new ^^